# Why do PAreview/codesniffer gripe about missing "scope modifier"?

Tags: 7, testing

I am writing a simpletest file for my Drupal module. It works OK, but when I use PAreview (automatic tool based upon PHP codesniffer to check correctness of Drupal code), I get the following error flagged: `No scope modifier specified for function "setUp".

My function `setUp` looks like this:

```
function setUp() {
  parent::setUp('realnamereg');
  variable_set('user_email_verification', FALSE);
}
```

Changing into into a public function fixes it:

```
public function setUp() {
  parent::setUp('realnamereg');
  variable_set('user_email_verification', FALSE);
}
```

Do anyone know why PAreview/code sniffer complains about this, and whether making the function `public` makes any difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As this example blog shows](http://ctankersley.com/2012/06/26/unit-testing-and-drupal-7-modules/), a testcase is a php class. The definition of `setUp` in the base class is a public function. Your implementation function of `setUp` must/should match the defined definition. So Parview bitches.

```
class MymoduleTestSuite extends DrupalUnitTestCase
{ ... }
```